# Eclipse JSP page parameter values trimmed by first space

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I am new to JSP Eclipse programming. I am using Eclipse to build the JSP page where it uses Tomcat 5.5 as the application server to run the page.

Now I have two JSP pages. Page one displays the link of filename from SAP BO.
When the user clicks this filename, it should display the values which are generated in the file.

Now the problem is: suppose the file name is `sales revenue`. 
When I click the link, the parameter value is trimmed to `sales`. Everything after the space is eliminated.

My code:

```
out.println("<a href=New.jsp?sDocName="+res+" target=_blank > click to view SQL and Export to Repository : "+res+" </a>");
```

... where `res` is the variable.

How can I get the whole filename included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `href` attribute in quotes, first of all, otherwise the HTML parser thinks the first space is the end of the attribute.

Second, URL encode the filename and use that as the `sDocName` parameter.

---

Untested; close:

```java
String url      = String.format("New.jsp?sDocName=%s", URLEncoder.encode(res));
String linkText = String.format("Click to view SQL and Export to Repository: %s", res);
String linkHtml = String.format("<a href='%s' target='_blank'>%s</a>", url, linkText);
out.println(linkHtml);
```

Comment: the res variable is dynamic, this code sit inside the for loop where it generates many links depending upon the number of files. "<a href=new.jsp?sDocName=res" .... not helping. any workaround. thanks

Comment: @user1462757 It doesn't matter if it's in a loop or not. Without knowing what you're actually doing it's impossible to help further.

Comment: Hi Dave thanks, ur rite i am don`t know this coding last week only i picked up just to get the results which i want.can u please re-write the code for me so i can use it. so it is helpfull for me.

Comment: @user1462757 No, I won't rewrite the code for you. Even if I would, I couldn't, because you don't show the exact code you're using. I told you how to fix the part you *do* show.

Comment: soory , i want only the line which i mentioned above to be rewritten.
ofcourse it is not possible to write the entire code for me. thanks

Comment: @user1462757 ... I don't see how that will help if you did what I told you to already.

Comment: Hi Dave, 
super,fantastic,excellent,bale...etc 
worked like a charm !!!. task finished. regretting that i should come here before. 
thanks DAve...but i am getting some warning message but results are fine.